# Creating Groups by Matching Values of Different Columns

Tags: r, group-by

I would like to create groups from a base by matching values.

I have the following data table:

```
now<-c(1,2,3,4,24,25,26,5,6,21,22,23)
before<-c(0,1,2,3,23,24,25,4,5,0,21,22)
after<-c(2,3,4,5,25,26,0,6,0,22,23,24)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(now,before,after))
```

which reproduces the following data:

```
   now before after
1    1      0     2
2    2      1     3
3    3      2     4
4    4      3     5
5   24     23    25
6   25     24    26
7   26     25     0
8    5      4     6
9    6      5     0
10   21      0    22
11   22     21    23
12   23     22    24
```

I would like to get:

```
    now before after group
1    1      0     2     A
2    2      1     3     A
3    3      2     4     A
4    4      3     5     A
5    5      4     6     A
6    6      5     0     A
7   21      0    22     B
8   22     21    23     B
9   23     22    24     B
10  24     23    25     B
11  25     24    26     B
12  26     25     0     B
```

I would like to reach the answer to this without using a "for" loop becouse the real data is too large.

Any you could provide will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear how your groups are defined.  Both contain `0`, for example.

Comment: what is your criteria for grouping?

Comment: Hi! @AndrewGustar, the grouping must be done matching the "now" columns with the "before" column of another row, the same must be done with the "now" column and the "after" column. In this way I will be connecting the succesive values and creating a group.

The "0" indicates that the following or preceding value does not exist.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way.  It is hard to avoid a for-loop as this is quite a tricky algorithm.  The objection to them is often on the grounds of elegance rather than speed, but sometimes they are entirely appropriate.

```
df$group <- seq_len(nrow(df)) #assign each row to its own group

stop <- FALSE #indicates convergence

while(!stop){
  pre <- df$group #group column at start of loop

  for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
    matched <- which(df$before==df$now[i] | df$after==df$now[i]) #check matches in before and after columns
    group <- min(df$group[i], df$group[matched]) #identify smallest group no of matching rows
    df$group[i] <- group #set to smallest group
    df$group[matched] <- group #set to smallest group
  }

  if(identical(df$group, pre)) stop <- TRUE #stop if no change
}

df$group <- LETTERS[match(df$group, sort(unique(df$group)))] #convert groups to letters
#(just use match(...) to keep them as integers - e.g. if you have more than 26 groups)

df <- df[order(df$group, df$now),] #reorder as required

df
   now before after group
1    1      0     2     A
2    2      1     3     A
3    3      2     4     A
4    4      3     5     A
8    5      4     6     A
9    6      5     0     A
10  21      0    22     B
11  22     21    23     B
12  23     22    24     B
5   24     23    25     B
6   25     24    26     B
7   26     25     0     B
```